# How to determine the excel cell value type(data type such as date, string, float etc.)

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to read the cell(1,1) value in the excel sheet, it is date in the format of `21-08-18`. 
I'm using the python package `xlrd` to read the value, it returns the float value ex. like 4567.0

```py
book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
compSheet = book.sheet_by_name("sheet_name")
cell_value = compSheet.cell_value(1, 1)
```

How to know the data type of the cell before reading the value whether it is `date` or `string` or `float` or etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a cell's type to see if it's a date and compare that to [xlrd's cell object definition](https://pythonhosted.org/xlrd3/cell.html) (or directly compare it to the number as seen in that table, as cell.ctype just returns a number).

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
compSheet = book.sheet_by_name("sheet_name")
cell = compSheet.cell(1,1)
if cell.ctype is xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE:
    print "Cell 1,1 is a date!"
```

Comment: This is what I'm expected, Thanks @JiyuuSensei